# Getting my own data from facebook using C# WITHOUT an application

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been googling for a couple of days, and I could not find any clue how to achieve that:

I have a desktop application(C#) in which I'd like to be able to login to my facebook profile, and pull some data from it(e.g. profile information, wall posts, likes on my posts, etc.)
Note that I DO NOT want to develop a facebook application, I simply would like to access my own user data.

As far as I see, the Graph API was designed to develop FB apps, and Graph API calls always need an access token, but I do not have token, since I do not use any Facebook application.

By now, the only way I see for that is to add a web browser component to my application, and login to the facebook through it, but  it's quite inconvenient to process the pure HTML, and, since the HTML itself can change at any time, the maintenance of the application would be a horror.

So I'd like to find some way to pull data from facebook in JSON format, like the Graph API, but without having a Facebook application.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Please help me with a similar topic which i have posted under [Facebook page Data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006708/getting-fb-page-data-from-facebook-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to access the data without a facebook application.

As you wrote, you need an access token for most graph requests, and in order to have an access token you need an application.
More than that, from what you wrote you'll need extra permissions which are not granted by default (for the user photos, wall posts, likes and so on).

Facebook can't just give you the info you see, the user has to grant a specific application the right to access their data, and because of that you must have a facebook app.

I don't see what the problem is though, just create a facebook app, it's not that complicated.

Comment: Maybe he's worried the app will start showing up in public lists etc. - it won't. Only you and anyone you explicitly share it with will be able to see that it exists. I've got an empty facebook app so I can play with the API and no-one's ever mentioned it and no-one's ever contacted me from Facebook about it. (Alternatively, do you not want an app so that you can access someone else's data without them having to grant permission to the app? I don't think that's possible either.)

Comment: You can also have the app in "sandbox mode"

Comment: OK, just to be clear: Let's say I'm John Smith; I log in to facebook through my desktop application(let's say there is a web browser component on my Form), and I'd like to pull my OWN wall's data, not somebody else's wall. So, in fact, since I'm already authenticated and logged in, it's obvious that I have the permission to see MY OWN wall; the problem is, that I can only access the wall data through the webbrowser as pure HTML, which is very inconvenient to process. So I'd like to have that data in some convenient format, like JSON, or XML, or whatever.

Comment: The web browser keeps a cookie with a session id and that id is attached to every request you make via the browser to facebook, that way they know who you are and that the request is authenticated. In order to do the same thing with the graph api you need to send an access token, which you can only get if you have an app.

Comment: At least, somebody could understand my problem :)

Comment: So, there's no way to get my own data in JSON/XML/whatever format when I simply log in to facebook with a web browser.

Comment: No, the web interface is designed for real users, the graph api (Application Programming Interface) is designed for what you need, but for that you'll need to create a fb app. You are right btw, parsing and extracting data from the html would be pain in the a**, especially if you take into account the frequent changes facebook are constantly making. I **strongly** advice against that approach, just create a fb app, it's really really not complicated.